# Sub-Menu Not Showing (Appearing Under Header)

Tags: wordpress

Project: lightertaste.com

The top menu has sub-menus under About, Nutrition & Fitness, and Resources, but it is not appearing correctly. Seems to be hidden under the menu.

Hoping someone can help me correct. Thanks!

```css
<div class="before-header"><section id="text-5" class="widget widget_text"><div class="widget-wrap">   <div class="textwidget"><div id="top-navigation">
<table><tr><td>

<nav id="top-navigation">
<ul>

<li>
<a href="http://www.lightertaste.com/">Home</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="/about/">About</a>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="/philosophy/">Philosophy</a></li>
     <li><a href="/faq/">FAQ</a></li>
     <li><a href="/work-with-me/">Work With Me</a></li>
     <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>

<li>
<a href="/recipe-index/">Recipe Index</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">Nutrition & Fitness</a>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Meal Plans</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Meal Prep</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Workouts</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">Resources</a>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Start a Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">My Blogroll</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Thank Yous</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">Shop</a>
</li>

</ul>
</nav>

</td><td>

<form class="search-top-form" method="get" action="http://www.lightertaste.com/">

<input class="search-top-input" type="text" name="s" id="s" value="" placeholder="Search" />

<input class="search-top-submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value=" " />
</form>

</td></tr></table>
</div>



<div class="top-subscribe-social">
<span class="social-top">

<a target="_blank" class="icon-rss top-social" href="#"></a>

<a target="_blank" class="icon-facebook top-social" href="#"></a>

<a target="_blank" class="icon-pinterest top-social" href="https://www.pinterest.com/lightertaste"></a>

<a target="_blank" class="icon-instagram top-social" href="https://www.instagram.com/lightertaste"></a>

<a target="_blank" class="icon-twitter top-social" href="https://twitter.com/lightertaste"></a>

<a target="_blank" class="icon-heart top-social" href="#"></a>

</span>
</div></div>
  </div>
```

```html
.before-header {
 background: #3d4646 !important;
 clear: both;
 padding: 5px !important;
 text-align: center;

 font-family: 'dosis-regular' !important;
 font-size: 14px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 text-transform: lowercase;
}

.before-header .widget {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 1000px !important;
}

/* Top Navigation
--------------------------------------------- */

#top-navigation ul {
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
}

#top-navigation ul a {
 display: block;
 color: #ffffff !important;
 font-weight: normal !important;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#top-navigation ul a:hover {
 color: #68a29c !important;
}

#top-navigation ul li {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 0px 10px;
}

#top-navigation ul li:first-child {
 margin-left: 0px;
}

#top-navigation ul li:hover {
 color: #79a7a5;
}

#top-navigation ul ul:before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 11px solid transparent;
 border-right: 11px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 11px solid #68a29c;
}

#top-navigation ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -2px;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 width: 150px;
}

#top-navigation ul ul li {
 float: none;
 margin: 0px;
}

#top-navigation ul ul a {
 display: block;
 background: #68a29c;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 12px;
}

#top-navigation ul ul a:hover {
 background: #3d4646;
 color: #ffffff;
}

#top-navigation ul ul ul {
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
}

#top-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Noticed this code in another area:

```css
/*
Top Ad
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.before-header {
 background: #f5f5f5;
 clear: both;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 10px 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.before-header img,
.before-header iframe {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.before-header .widget {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 1100px;
}
```